# Java application uptime not displayed as desired

Tags: java, time, date-format

I am trying to get my application to print its uptime on the user's command, however it will produce the following when executed:
`Current up-time: 01:00:07:34`
Whereas the actual uptime is `00:00:07:34`. I spent a while going through similar questions to this, and most said about either setting the time zone to GMT or using an external time API. As I am trying to keep dependencies to a minimum I am trying to avoid using an external API just to simply get an uptime. I set the time zone to GMT but all it did was fix the hour (It used to display `01:01:07:34` as the uptime).

My code is something like this:

```
            case "uptime":
                long uptime = System.currentTimeMillis()-MainClass.getStartTime();
                DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("DD:HH:mm:ss");
                formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
                System.out.printf("Current up-time: %s\n", formatter.format(new Date(uptime)));
                return true;
```

Anyone know how I can get this to produce a sane output?

Comment: You are not formatting a date (a point in time) but a time interval. I would do the calculations myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Date(long time)` constructor creates a new object containing the date *time* milliseconds after January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT (see [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28long%29)).  You actually want to format a time period, not a date. The JDK provides no methods for that. Either you implement a period formatter by yourself, or you use a library like joda that provides one (joda: [`PeriodFormatter`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatter.html), [`PeriodFormatterBuilder`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatterBuilder.html)).

Answer (score 0):

`D` is the Day of Year. Use `d` for day of month.

```
  DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:HH:mm:ss");
```